# Swift: Add file attachments (not only images) into PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, pdf-generation, attachment

How can I add other file attachments than images into a PDF natively in Swift or with "free" libraries? I know it is i.e. possible with the commercial library "quick pdf library" from debenu.com.

Today my working Swift3 code looks like this but does not include the above mentioned file attachment functionality:

```
// function PDF creation

func createPDFcontent(_ msgIDfunc: String) {

    self.doctitle = msgIDfunc
    self.author = "blabla"
    self.creator = "blabla"
    self.subject = msgIDfunc

    var infoDict = [String: AnyObject]()
    infoDict[kCGPDFContextTitle as String] = self.doctitle as NSString?
    infoDict[kCGPDFContextAuthor as String] = self.author as NSString?
    infoDict[kCGPDFContextCreator as String] = self.creator as NSString?
    infoDict[kCGPDFContextSubject as String] = self.subject as NSString?

    let HtmlForPDF = "<b><i><font color='red'>+++ Hello World +++</i></b></font>"

    // new hmtl version
    let frmt = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: HtmlForPDF)

    //  set print format

    let render = UIPrintPageRenderer()
    render.addPrintFormatter(frmt, startingAtPageAt: 0)

    //  create Paper Size for print

    let page = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 595.2, height: 841.8)
    let printable = page.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)

    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: page), forKey: "paperRect")
    render.setValue(NSValue(cgRect: printable), forKey: "printableRect")

    // create PDF context and draw

    let filedata = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(filedata, CGRect.zero, infoDict)  

    for i in 1...render.numberOfPages {

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
        let bounds = UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds()
        render.drawPage(at: i - 1, in: bounds)
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]

    filedata.write(toFile: "\(documentsPath)/blabla.pdf", atomically: true)

}
```

Any hint is welcome.

Comment: Anyone who can help? :-/

Comment: Not aware that this works with CGPDF. It mostly helps you parse, but not edit a PDF. We had to move to our own PDF parser/writer before we could offer this feature in PSPDFKit. https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/how-to-embed-files-using-file-annotations/